How do I prove local minima are global?
This function $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-4 x y+1$ has two local minima at $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. It's minimum value is $-1$.
I would like to prove that $f(x,y) \geq -1$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, that is,
$$x^4 +y^4 -4xy +1 \geq -1 \ \ \mbox{ or } \ \  x^4 +y^4 -4xy \geq -2.$$
I've tried to write $x^4 +y^4 -4xy = (x^2+y^2)^2 - 2 x^2 y^2 - 4xy$ and I've also tried to think that, as $x^4+y^4 \geq 0$, than $x^4 +y^4 -4xy \geq -4xy$, but I couldn't get to a conclusion. Does anyone can help me?

Hint: Look at the equality cases, and try to guess what the Completing The Square looks like. It's possible to write the expression as a sum of squares.  $\quad$ Further hint: How do we get rid of the likely cross term $ \pm 2x^2 y^2$? Well if it was a $-$, then we could $ + 2x^2 y^2$ in the sum of squares. (You decided to go with a $+$, which means we have to $ - 2x^2 y^2$, which isn't that easy to deal with)

Find a suitable sum of squares. You actually came close to it.
$$ x^4 + y^4 - 4xy + 2 $$

 $$= x^4 + y^4  - 2x^2y^2 + 2x^2y^2 - 4xy + 2 $$


 $$ = (x^2 - y^2 ) ^2 + 2(xy-1)^2 $$

Hence, the expression is $ \geq 0 $.
Equality holds iff $ x^2 = y^2, xy = 1$ or that $(x,y) = (1, 1), (-1, -1)$.

Thank you so much! I was close! What about the maximum? Should I take limits?

I see! It is enough to exhibit a counterexample, right?

The point $(0,0)$ is not a maximum global because $f(1,0) = 2 > 1 = f(0,0)$.

@Alice $(0,0)$ is not a local maximum, but rather a saddle point. (EG Along $x+y=0$,  $f(x, -x) = 2x^4 + 4x^2$ which has a minimum at $ (0, 0)$). Hence, this bounding by Sum of Squares idea will not (easily) work.

Sorry! That' true. I made a confusion with another example I was studying. I'll edit my question. Thanks.

Another way... (informal)
Critical points are found from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$
which is the system $4x^3-4y=4y^3-4x=0$ as $(0,0),(1,1), (-1,-1)$ with function values $-1,1,-1$ respectively.
On the other hand, $f\to +\infty$ while $x$ or $y$ goes to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Therefore, global minimum of $f$ is $-1$.

Looking at the limits when $x$ or $y$ goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ is not sufficient (we may have $f\to -\infty$ along some slant line). What you need is the limit when $||(x,y)|| \to \infty$.

@Taladris You are right. This is not a (topological) proof. I have to make it formal. (,,>﹏<,,)

Here is a sketch, I let you check/complete the details.

Show that $f(x,y)\to \infty$ when $||(x,y)||\to\infty$.
This means that, there exists $K>0$ such that, if $||(x,y)||>K$, then $f(x,y)>0$.
Let $B$ be the disk of center $(0,0)$ and radius $K$. Then $B$ is compact and $f$ is continuous on $B$. By the Extreme Value Theorem, $f$ has a global minimum on $B$ (also, a global maximum, but that's not the question).
We can choose $K$ sufficiently large so that the critical point of $f$ are not in $B$. Therefore, the global minimum on $B$ is a local minimum of $f$.
Such local minimums are $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. Since $f(\pm1,\pm1)=-1$, they are both the global minimums on $B$.
Since $f(x,y)\ge 0$ for any $(x,y)$ outside $B$, they are the global minimum of $f$ on $\mathbb R^2$ as well.


Thanks for your comment. I would give upvote to your answer but İ didn't understand some points in your answer. I have to go back and study some more advanced calculus.
